# Is the Scooby-verse a single universe or a multi-verse?

Tags: scooby-doo

I just finished watching Scooby-Doo! Mysteries Incorporated on Netflix. It is set during the teens' high school years and ends with their graduation (all 4 are in the same graduating class). In the final episode, they make plans for a cross-country mystery-solving road trip.

Ignoring the fact that a couple of the movies are live-action, does everything in the Scooby-verse occur in a single timeline? Or are there multiple timelines?

Comment: Question migrated at OP's request.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no fixed continuity between many of the series. For one, Mystery Inc takes place present year, while they are teens. Yet some of the originals take place back in 1960/1970, with era appropriate real life characters, while they are adults. Immediately breaks continuity.

Yet we have this in Cyber Chase, referencing years before the movie happens:

And this in Mystery Inc.

Referencing 13 Ghosts, again while they are adults.

The shoes only care about internal continuity, not franchise wide continuity. But they will reference the others without problem.

Comment: Wow, I believe that's the first time I ever saw Scooby sniff another dog's ass before — even if it was his doppelganger's.

Comment: @cde I dunno, after all, he can taste the virtual fries...

Comment: @cde The first video has gone missing. Any chance you could describe what was in it?